# String array to a collection of Integer?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

What is an easy way to convert a `String[]` to a `Collection<Integer>`? This is how I'm doing it right now but not sure if it's good:

```
String[] myStringNumbers;

Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList(myStringNumbers).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()).boxed().collect(
                    Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to make an intermediate array.  Just parse and collect (with static import of `Collectors.toList`):

```
Arrays.stream(myStringNumbers).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

It is unnecessary to use `parseInt` as it will box the result to the collection, and as @Misha stated you can use `Arrays.stream` to create the stream. So you can use the following:

```
Arrays.stream(myStringNumbers).map(Integer::decode).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please note that this *does not* do any error handling (and the numbers should not start with `0`, `#` or `0x` in case you do not want surprises). If you want just base 10 numbers, `Integer::valueOf` is a better choice.

Comment: The `int` values are boxed in either case, so whether you use `valueOf` or `parseInt` makes no difference. And it’s quite strange to recommend the use of a different method like `decode` followed by a warning about the surprises caused by the fact that this method has a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think:

```
String[] myStringNumbers = {"1", "2"};
List<Integer> list = Stream.of(myStringNumbers).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope it can be some help. :)